# Japanese speech to text to use kanji for numbers by default?

Tags: iphone, ios, voice-dictation, japanese

I use speech-to-text to practice Japanese. When I say numbers in Japanese, it inputs Arabic numerals for the number parts of the words instead of kanji.

For example, if I say "one" in Japanese, or "ichi", I get `1`, but I want to get `一`. Similarly "futari" gives me `2人` instead of `二人`.

Is there a way to set it up so that speech-to-text uses kanji for numbers?